# How does mysql views get autimatically updated

Tags: mysql, view

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE t (qty INT, price INT);
```

And the  following view:

```
CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT qty, price, qty*price AS value FROM t where t.price > 50;
```

If I insert new record matching the where clause of the view, these records will be returns when I do a `select * from v`

But I'm unsure how that works.
Does the view gets updated on `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` or does it get updated every time I'm querying the view? Meaning that on every single query on the view, the following sql query(`SELECT qty, price, qty*price AS value FROM t where t.price > 50`) will be performed as well?

If I were to create a view by joining some relatively large table together I wouldn't want the underlying SQL query to be executed every time I query the view, that wouldn't be efficient.

Also, where/how does the view get stored?

Comment: Views in MySQL are inefficient, and are of questionable utility. One instance where they are useful is in simplifing the process of updating values contained within an EAV model, but the view has to be very carefully constructed in order to make that possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View doesn't store any data. Whenever you query the view, your are actually querying the underlying table.

For views that do store data, refer to **materialized view**.

Comment: ...which are absent of from MySQL (currently version 8.x)